# How upload APK with FacebookSDK on google play?

Tags: android, facebook, hash, facebook-sdk-3.1

I am creating apps in which I am using  facebook SDK for posting purpose,which works successfully but when I add signature(before uploading to play Store) to app at that time it doesn't works(doesn't get posted on Facebook Wall) ....So What to do ?

Answer (score 0):

have you added new keyhash with keystore
keytool -exportcert -alias  -keystore  | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

using this command for more details chaeck its developer site: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Comment: also you can find correct keyhash when you install signed apk in your device and call for facebook it will show error dialog with keyhash which you have to enter in your application created on facebook.